# Why does the skipgram model takes more time to train compared to cbow?

Tags: neural-networks, word2vec, word-embeddings

I have been using gensim's word2vec implementation. Through my experiments, I learnt that Skipgram model takes 8x more time compared to CBOW on the same data, for the same number of dimensions and all the other parameters being constant.
Why is this? Is there a possible explaination?

Answer (score 2):

There could be different approaches, but Gensim is using this one:

- In SkipGram model, each window generates up to `window_size` (random size, it's called reduced window in the code) pairs to train.
  See [`train_batch_sg`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L147) method.
- In CBOW method, each window generates exactly one pair to train, which updates the model for *all context words* in the reduced window *at once*.
  See [`train_batch_cbow`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L177) method.

This explains the difference in training time between SkipGram and CBOW.